# Google Analytics Page/Content Tracking

Tags: javascript, django, google-analytics

When using Google Analytics with say Django.  Is the tracking code on my base template enough?  How can I track when say a PDF is opened?

EDIT:
For tracking pdf's that are opened in browser, would this code be appropriate?
The .cs-link and .brochure-link classes are on the links for the different pdf types.

```
$(document).on('click', '.cs-link', function() {
    ga('send', 'event', {
        eventCategory: 'Case Study',
        eventAction: 'click',
        eventLabel: event.target.href,
        transport: 'beacon'
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.brochure-link', function() {
    ga('send', 'event', {
        eventCategory: 'Brochure',
        eventAction: 'click',
        eventLabel: event.target.href,
        transport: 'beacon'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnot want to answer, because it is just too broad and can be googled easily. but let me give my two cents.

In Django, if you correctly build base.html and inherit it correctly in all pages that need base.html, the tracking code which is in base.html should be available in all templates that inherited base.html.

as for PDF, you may want to create events in Google Analytics, since the clicks on PDFs won't be normally tracked by  standard tracking code. here is [how you create events in GA](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events).

`gaq.push()` event is now deprecated and you should not use it. Instead you should use the `send` event with `ga` command queue. [here is how you use it](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/#the_javascript_tracking_snippet).

Comment: Thanks. I really was just asking if pdf views were tracked without push. Big help.

Comment: @shenk you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

So long as it is present and correct on every page, Google Analytics will track all traffic, with data such as page load times, browsers etc.

The way that the web is designed means that a lot of information can be extracted in this simple manner: by tracking what pages a user goes to when. However there are some things that won't be tracked in this manner: essentially any interaction that doesn't cause a new page of your site to load, such as

- Download links
- Exit links
- Clicks to open a menu
- Interaction with in-page objects

These will require event tracking, which is where you need to pull out the custom code.

Comment: So assuming I wanted to track when a PDF is opened in the browser.  Would the code in my edit be appropriate?

Comment: I'm afraid I usually use Google Tag Manager, so I can't help. I recommend you simply test it.